# Central limit theorem example

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

I am not able to make progress with the following exercise.

Assignment:

The advertising board is lit by one 100W bulb. Using the central limit theorem determine the minimum number of bulbs needed for advertising board lighting for 20 000 hours with probability at least 0.9. Bulb life has the exponential distribution and average life of the 100W bulb is 600 hour.

My progress:

$X_ \text{ ..... } \text{total time of bulb life}$

$X_i \sim Exp(\lambda)$

$Ex= \frac{1}{\lambda} \implies \lambda = \frac{1}{Ex} $

$ Ex = 600$

$ \lambda = \frac{1}{600} $

$Dx = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} $

$Dx = \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{600})^2} = 360000$

$X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

$ \mu = \frac{1}{600}; \sigma^2=360000$

Now I am don't how to continue. I expected some equation like this: 
$ P(X > 20000) \geq 0.9$

Can you please give me any hints on how to continue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
S = X_1+X_2+...+X_n \xrightarrow[]{d} N( n\mu, n\sigma^2),
$ where $\mu=1/\lambda=EX_i,$ and $\sigma^2 = 1/\lambda^2=Var(X_i).$

Then, 
$$P(S>T_0) = 1-P(S<T_0) = 1-\Phi(\frac{T_0 - n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma})>0.9,
$$
where $T_0=20,000.$

Thus, 
$$\Phi(\frac{T_0 - n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma})<0.1 \implies \frac{T_0 - n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma} < q_{0.1},
$$ where $q_{0.1} = -1.281552$ is the tenth percentile of the standard normal (corresponding to the probability of standard normal equal to $0.1$.

Solving for $n$ in the quadratic equation $T_0 - n\mu = \sqrt{n}\sigma q_{0.1}$ yields $n=42$.

Comment: Thank you for the more detailed description. Now I understand the procedure. Can I ask you how do you get $T_0 - n\mu = \sqrt{n}\sigma q_{0.1}$ from $\frac{T_0 - n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma} < q_{0.1}$ ? Shouldn't it be $T_0 - n\mu < \sqrt{n}\sigma q_{0.1}$?

Comment: In order to solve a quadratic equation in a usual way -- hence the '=' sign.

Comment: Ok, I'm still not able to get $n=42$ the result. Can you please give me some tip on how to continue with  $T_0 - n\mu = \sqrt{n}\sigma q_{0.1}$? I tried various adjustment of equations but still nothing.

Comment: Square both sides of the equation, collect the $n$-terms and solve.

Comment: Can you please check my progress?
$
T_0 - n\mu = \sqrt{n}\sigma q_{0.1} \\
(T_0 - n\mu)^2 = (\sqrt{n}\sigma q_{0.1})^2 \\
T_0^2 - 2T_0n\mu +n^2\mu^2 = n\sigma^2q_{0.1}^2 \\
T_0^2 - 2T_0n\mu - n\sigma^2q_{0.1}^2 + n^2\mu^2 = 0
$

Comment: Yes, just solve the quadratic in $n$: $\mu^2 n^2 -n(2T_0\mu + \sigma^2q_{0.1}^2) + T_0^2 = 0.$

Comment: I got:

$\mu^2 n^2 -n(2T_0\mu + \sigma^2q_{0.1}^2) + T_0^2 = 0 \\
\frac{n^2}{600} - n(2*20,000*\frac{1}{600} + 360,000^2*(-1.2815)^2)+20,000^2 = 0$


But if I try to solve, result is strange. Result by WolframAlpha - [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((n%5E2)%2F600)+-+n*(2*20000*(1%2F600)%2B(360000%5E2)*(-1.2815)%5E2)%2B20000%5E2+%3D+0)

Comment: check the WolframAlpha link now

Comment: Which link do you mean?

Comment: The one you've sent in your previous comment. You have wrong values plugged in for $\mu^2$ and $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91687/discussion-between-user4362081-and-dnqxt).

Comment: Definitely, the final result equation is $((n^2)*600^2) - n*(2*20000*(600)+(360000)*(-1.2815)^2)+20000^2 = 0$

Answer (score 0):

Adopting your notation, the central limit theorem intuitively says that for very large integers $n$, the distribution of 
$$ \frac1{\sqrt n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i $$
is approximately $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.
I believe the exercise is asking you to say that the answer $n$ lightbulbs that you need is large enough to use the approximation:
$$ \frac1{\sqrt n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2) \tag{1}$$
This will be useful, because you can write the event of $n$ light bulbs lasting $20,000$-hours in terms of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$.

Try to do this, and then rewrite it in terms of the scaled distribution in (1).
You will instead see that you want $P(X\geq f(n)) \geq 0.9$, where $f(n)$ is an expression that depends on $n$ — not only $20,000$.

Comment: I don't fully understand of step:  This will be useful because you can write the event of n light bulbs lasting 20,000-hours in terms of  $X_1,...,X_n$. Can you please explain more details?

Comment: Yeah! Since $X_i$ is the bulb life of the $i$-th light bulb, the combined life of $n$ light bulbs is $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$. To say that the $n$ light bulbs lasts more than $20,000$-hours would mean that $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n\geq 20,000$.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear to me. How I can use claim $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n\geq 20,000$  in the next steps please?