# Central limit theorem calculate probability

Tags: probability

I recently stumbled upon this question posted here on stackexchange:  [Central limit theorem example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3165004/central-limit-theorem-example?newreg=ed656f353e7845b48d3c49b35c973a05)

I was wondering how you would solve this problem if instead of determining the number of bulbs needed for the board lighting for 20 000 hours with 0.9 probability, you instead were given the number of bulbs and had to find the probability at which it would sustain the 20 000 hours.

I'm using the formula:

$Zn = \frac{Sn - nμ}{σ\sqrt{n}}$

I'm trying to calculate:

$P(S42 >= 20 000)$

where:

$μ = 600$

$n = 42$

$σ^2=360 000$

However, when I plug these figures into the formula above, I get the results: -1.33729...

My intuition tells me that this number should be positive. So I'm thinking my approach is incorrect. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: "Thanks!" You´re welcome! And thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

The result (argument of the function) is positive. $P(S_n\geq 20,000)=1-P(S_n< 20,000)$

$P(S_n< 20,000)\approx \Phi \left(\frac{20,000-42\cdot 600}{\sqrt{42}\cdot 600} \right)=\Phi(-1.33729)$

The standard normal distribution is symmetric around $z=0$. Therefore  $\Phi(-1.33729)=1-\Phi(1.33729)$

In combination with the first line we get $1-P(S_n< 20,000)\approx 1-[1-\Phi(1.33729)]=\Phi(1.33729) \ \checkmark$

Comment: Btw, $\Phi(1.33729)=0.909436>0.9$, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_(-infty)%5E(1.33729)+1%2F(sqrt(2*pi))*+e%5E((-x%5E2)%2F2)+dx)

Answer (score 0):

Your formula should be:

$Zn = \frac{Sn - μ}{σ\sqrt{n}}$

this will give you 1.33729 = 0.9082%